# What happens when you initialize EM with a consistent estimate?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, latent-variable, expectation-maximization

I have a certain family of models with latent random variables (not observed in the data), which I have a consistent estimator for.

I now run EM on top of it, meaning, I get the consistent estimation, and initialize EM with it and run it for another few iterations.

I know that EM has problem with local maxima, and also specifically for the model family I am handling as well.

But, however, I think when you initialize EM with a consistent estimate, you can only improve your estimate (make it more efficient) and you won't have issues with local maxima.

Is there anything in the literature to support that?

Comment: I don’t think you will have a general result: if the estimate is consistent but has huge variance, it can be near to a local maximum which is not the true maximum... to discard it, you’d have to show that (with high probability) your first estimator is in the basin of attraction of the global maximum likelihood. This seems (to me!) a very technical thing to do – and I think the proof has to be adapted to your particular case.

However I think the heuristic is good and that in general your idea will give good result. A simulation study could help to assess the properties of the method?

Comment: Note that if EM has a problem with local maxima, then just about any algorithm will.  Local maxima is a feature/problem related to the function you are trying to optimise, not of the algorithm you choose to optimise it with.  Your question does not make this clear, so I thought it was worthwhile to mention.  As an example, you can use an EM algorithm to fit logistic regression, but there will be no local maxima/minima problem as logistic regression is a convex optimisation problem.

Answer (score 1):

A well-known property of the EM algorithm is that it guarantees to increase the log-likelihood of the current estimate on every iteration. So, if the estimate you use as an initialization does not correspond to a local maxima of the likelihood function, it is natural to expect that EM will do some good.

Answer (score 0):

*you can only improve your estimate (make it more efficient)* -> Yes, as hrOnix said, the EM algorithm always allow you to increase the log-likelihood if you are not already in a local maxima.

*and you won't have issues with local maxima* -> Not true. The EM algorithm can still get closer and closer to a local maxima, and you'll never know if it is a global maxima (in most of the cases). This problem don't disappear if you use a better estimate. Using a better estimate can only allow you to converge to a good solution (local maxima) faster.